# sudo does not import /etc/environment on Debian 9

Tags: debian, sudo, pam

I have configured my proxy in `/etc/environment`.

When I become root by

```
sudo su -
```

the proxy environment variables are set. But when I become root by

```
sudo -i
```

the proxy environment variables are missing.

It turns out that `/etc/pam.d/su` includes the necessary line to read `/etc/environment`.

```
# parsing /etc/environment needs "readenv=1"
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
```

But `/etc/pam.d/sudo` does not include the above configuration.

Is this a bug in the distribution or does a specific reason exist that `sudo` does not include the environment?

Comment: It may be worth looking at the "Command environment" section of the sudoers man page

Comment: What happens if you `su -`?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give an answer to your question. Just a little bit more research: pam_env.so in sudo is also missing in earlier Debian versions (jessie and wheezy). "sudo -E" would be a possible workaround, but unfortunately also does not work in Debian. On the other hand, both is possible in Fedora 28.